# Не работает URL изображения в html

Tags: html

[image: Image Question]

Всем привет, учусь, для большинства мой вопрос будет из разряда глупых но, у меня получается поставить абсолютный адрес изображения, когда ставлю его - всё работает. Но, хочу разобраться и понимать, почему так - я ставлю изображение с указанием папки, как написано в статьях по прописыванию линков к изображениям, локализация изображение и код - в скрине. Почему не работает? Прошу отнестись коллегиально и объяснить, что не так. Сам html файл лежит в корне, папка с картинкой - в корне, картинка - в ней. Что не так в данном случае?

Comment: большая буква `I`

Comment: Небольшой update: одну и две точки перед слешом ставил, заглавную букву менял с малой на большую и обратно - НЕ работает(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, как у Вас написано, при загрузке с локального диска, браузер будет искать картинку в папке `C:/Images`.

Такой URL картинки сработает только если Вы разместили ее на сайте и `learning1_1.html` находится в корне этого сайта.

А для вашего случая - уберите первый `/`: `image/logo_SapiensMedical.png`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Завтра попробую - искренне верю, что всё заработает - сразу поставлю галку о решении вопроса.

Comment: Всё работает, ещё раз спасибо